# Употребление предлогов на, за и через - временные контрукции

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слова, выражения, предлоги

Объясните пожалуйста как правильно употреблять предлоги за,на,через(или без предлогов) когда речь идёт о времени.

насколько я понимаю,  предлог НА отвечает на вопрос *"как долго?"*, а предлог ЗА отвечает на вопрос *"за сколько?"*. Можно употреблять предлог за с глаголами несовершенно вида? например: "я переводил статью за час  " вместо "я перевёл статью за час" ?

У меня есть такое задание где нужно употребить слова, данные в скобках с предлогами на, за, через или без предлога.

например:

1. после школы мы не видели друг друга ... ( 5 лет)
2. он уехал в командировку ... (неделя)
3. я читал журнал ... (час)
4. я прочитал весь журнал ... (час)
5. он очень изменился ... (5 лет)

вот мои ответы:

1. после школы мы не видели друг друга 5 лет
2. он уехал в командировку **на** неделю
3. я читал журнал **за** час
4. я прочитал весь журнал **за** час
5. он очень изменился **через** 5 лет

Comment: 5. "за" лучше бы смотрелось, мне кажется.

Comment: @Dmitry а в третьем предложении можно без предлога?

Comment: да, есть и такой контекст, что можно и без.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

после школы мы не видели друг друга ... ( 5 лет)

он уехал в командировку ..на/через (неделю)

я читал журнал ... (час)

я прочитал весь журнал ..за/через (час)

он очень изменился ..за. (5 лет)

Некорректное задание, потому что в некоторых случаях возможны варианты, но если выбирать один, то при таком порядке слов предпочтительнее первый.